# Find the salary of the youngest and eldest employee in each department

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join, having

There are two tables

```
1) Employee
id | Name |  Department | Dob 

2) Salary
id | salary
```

I want to find the salary of the youngest and eldest employee in each department.
But using the the following query i am not able to get the correct id,salary.

```
SELECT salary.id,employee.Dept,salary.salary,MIN(employee.DoB) 
from employee 
INNER JOIN salary ON salary.id = employee.id  GROUP by Dept
```

***The above query is returning correct Dob but the ids and the salary are not matching with the Date of birth.***

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, just use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        e.*, 
        s.salary,
        row_number() over(partition by department order by dob asc) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by department order by dob desc) rn_desc
    from employee e
    inner join salary s on s.id = employee.id
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

In earlier versions, one option is to join with an aggregate query:

```
select e.*, s.salary
from employee e
inner join salary s on s.id = employee.id
inner join (
    select department, min(dob) min_dob, max(dob) max_dob 
    from employee
    group by department
) d on d.department = e.department and e.dob in (d.min_dob, d.max_dob)
```

Comment: Thank You for your response Both queries worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use `=` twice with correlated subqueries:

```
select s.*, e.department
from salary join
     employee e
     on s.id = e.id
where e.dob = (select min(e2.dob) from employee e where e2.department = e.department) or
      e.dob = (select max(e2.dob) from employee e where e2.department = e.department) ;
```

With an index on `employee(department, dob)`, I would expect this to have very good performance.